# a 'search and extract' batch file

Tags: batch-file, search, extract

I'd like to ask your assistance in the following batch script:
- Search for a specific file in all drives
- If found extract an archive to that directory
Thank you in advance

**Edit** code added from the comments area

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "C:\test.txt" 2^>nul') do set place1=%%F
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "C:\copy.rar" 2^>nul') do set place2=%%F
unrar x place2\copy.rar *.gif place1
```

Comment: I'd wager that 'search all drives' is one of the most asked questions ever. Perform a search, try the code found, then update your question by appending your code to it if you become stuck. _Remember that this isn't a 'you tell us what you want and we'll do it for you for free' type of site_.

Comment: Not the search part is problematic but the 'how to use its result'. Tho thanks for your quick reply even if it didn't help much.

Comment: When I said 'Perform a search' I meant of this site. _(perhaps looking at "search all drives" and also "extract an archive")_. Take the code resulting from those searches and manipulate them to better serve your specifics. If you have a problem during that manipulation then that's what you ask for help with, by posting it here with what happens when it is run and what was intended to happen.

Comment: I've tried my best.
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "C:\test.txt" 2^>nul') do set place1=%%F
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "C:\copy.rar" 2^>nul') do set place2=%%F
unrar x place2\copy.rar *.gif place1

Comment: I've added the above to your question, just add a few details to it now to improve your question and then request that the 'hold' is removed such that you can get answers.

Comment: I don't know what else could be added nor how to request that.

Comment: The information about the on hold status can be seen in the 'help center' link provided in the on hold message. Additionally the details required are provided there, my previous responses and [ask]. If you edit your question and make sure you've adequately fulfilled the requirements, it will be voted on for reopening according to the time limits mentioned. Other than that you may be fortunate enough that a Moderator reopens the post quicker. The key here is that you have a little time to maximise your chances of getting the hold removed.

Comment: Might want to read this: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html